# Digital Ocean unable to access console

Tags: console, digital-ocean, droplet

i am unable to access my droplet console in digital ocean ,it is giving a notification "enable the new Droplet Console for native-like terminal access to your Droplet from your browser."
To enable the Droplet Console, log in to your Droplet as root or as a user with sudo access. Once connected, download and execute the agent installation script with the following command to enable the console immediately:

```sh
wget -qO- https://repos-droplet.digitalocean.com/install.sh | sudo bash
```

but i am having no access to its console so i have no idea where i can give this command, putty is also not giving any response. [screenshot of the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJbWp.png)

Answer (score 8):

TLDR; run it in the Recovery Console.

I know this is an old question but posting in case any one else lands here in a search.

Click the "Launch Recovery Console" button in the "Recovery Console" section of Droplet's Access page.

Sign in as `root`. If you don't know the password, use the "Reset root Password" button in the "Reset root password" section below.

paste the `wget` command you have there from the "Droplet Console" section and run it. It may take a bit.

When that completes, the first section "Droplet Console" should now update and have a button to "Launch Droplet Console"

You may need to log out of and back into Digital Ocean before the Droplet Console will launch successfully.

Comment: Thanks for this answer sure it will help someone if he is looking out for this.

Answer (score 5):

You are unable to connect to the console because by mistake you `started the ufw without allowing ssh`

To get console back:
Step 1: Go to `Launch Recovery Console`

[image]

Step 2: after logging in run: `ufw allow ssh`

Step 3: you will see something like:

[image]

Step 4: Try to login with SSH, it will be successful!

Comment: thanks for your answer, although the issue I found was that the server went to panic mode so I recovered my files by getting into recovery mode

Answer (score 4):

It fixed itself for me in a day.
Possibly, you need to logout/login.
And also I've added 2FA to my account.
After that actions I finally can use that feature.

Answer (score 2):

Digital Ocean provides extensive documentation:

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/putty/

Once you're `ssh`'d into the Droplet, you need to run that command.

Then:

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/connect-with-console/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's helpful for anyone that's using the droplet console. The droplet console is difficult to use in production. It can't scroll through its output, its window size is small, and doesn't expand when maximized, and it incorrectly formats pasted text.

Comment: Instead, use Visual Studio Code. You can create, open, edit, and transfer files on the virtual machine from within the code editor like you would on your regular computer. You can run commands on multiple terminal applications in parallel. It also doesn't have any of the limitations that the web-based terminal application had.

Comment: Link to tutorial: https://medium.com/p/44afcc954d38

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I disallowed root access permission and, in the config file.

#Solution

if you have backup enable just rollback to previous backup before the incident.

This solved my problem